Is there a simple debugger for batch files?
I am debugging a complicated set of dos batch files that change directories, set variables create files, and call each other. I am on Windows 10. I know, I can edit each file and add @echo and pause every while. But this is tedious and error prone. Surely, I will screw up things even more. I recall in the times of Turbo-C there was a way to execute a program one line at a time and inspect the program's state. All this, without editing the code. Isn't there such a way (or cmd.exe's mode) for batch-files?

That's really the only way to do it. You might find it slightly easier if you simply comment out all of the inital @echo off lines, though.

DOS and cmd are very different, so if you use cmd then don't call it DOS batch files

Do you really need to use batch files? Python or powershell are much easier to use and both have debuggers

You are either asking about configuring or using a cmd.exe, (possibly with other built-in utilities), or asking for software recommendations. StackOverflow is for your programming code problems, not software use or configuration, and questions looking for software/tools/modules etc. are specifically off topic too.

The short answer is definitely NO.
But...
What I do is reserve a prefix character for debugging variables, say #.
Then
call monitor somestring

at points of interest
where monitor.bat in the path contains
rem goto :eof
@echo off
setlocal
echo =============================================
echo monitor %*
set #
echo =============================================
pause

Then in your batch-to-be-debugged, you can put, eg.
call monitor place-identifier critical data %%b %%c %%q

to report the code location, critical data and variables, the monitored variables and anything else you like, being careful to take care of such things as varying errorlevel if you extend the report between the === lines (eg if exist filename (echo filename exists) else (echo filename missing))
"removing" the debugging can be done by simply removing the rem from monitor.bat (at a time-cost of still executing the call, but you still retain instant enter-debug-mode by re-remming monitor.bat)
